# Proper way to get SHA-1 for signing Flutter application

Tags: flutter

I'm little confused about how to get SHA-1 key for console.cloud.google.com.

The flutter documentation says: create a keystore.jks file anywhere and use it from [project]/android/app/build.gradle.
[Configure signing in gradle](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#signing-the-app)

Others says to use C:\Users\yourusernamehere.android\debug.keystore

and get sha-1 by running: ./gradlew signingReport

[flutter generate sha1](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/whatever/flutter+generate+sha1)

What is the correct way to sign?

Answer (score 0):

go to the android directory of your project and run `gradlew signingReport`

Comment: I created an own jks file. The signingReport lists this file's content, too. I gave SHA1- and SHA-256 on firebase console, downloaded google-seervices.json, but google authentication says: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: